# pd.DataFrame on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What does pd.DataFrame does on a dataframe? Please see the code below.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                           

In [2]: a = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3], b=[4,5,6]))                                                                                                  

In [3]: b = pd.DataFrame(a)                                                                                                                           

In [4]: a['c'] = [7,8,9]                                                                                                                              

In [5]: a                                                                                                                                             
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

In [6]: b                                                                                                                                             
Out[6]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

In [7]: a.drop(columns='c', inplace=True)                                                                                                             

In [8]: a                                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [9]: b                                                                                                                                             
Out[9]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

In `In[3]`, the function `pd.DataFrame` is applied on a dataframe `a`. It turns out that the ids of `a` and `b` are different. However, when a column is added to `a`, the same column is added to `b`, but when we drop a column from `a`, the column is not dropped from `b`. So what does `pd.DataFrame` does? Are `a` and `b` the same object or different? What should we do to `a` so that we drop the column from `b`? Or, how do we prevent a column from being added to `b` when we add a column to `a`?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid your statements at all cost. Better would be to make a dataframe as such:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5], 'c':[6,7,8]})
```

The above result is a dataframe, with indices and column names.

You can add a column to df, like this:

```
df['d'] = [8,9,10]
```

And remove a column to the dataframe, like this:

```
df.drop(columns='c',inplace=True)
```

Comment: What I intend to do is to use this in a function 
```def fun(x):
    x = pd.DataFrame(x)
    x['new_column'] = x['old_column']
    // do something with x['old_column']
    x['old_column'] = x['new_column']
    x.drop(columns='new_column', inplace=True)
```
The reason why for the line `x = pd.DataFrame(x)` is so that my function can take in either a dictionary or a data frame. However, this function is problematic in the sense that the `new_line` isn't dropped from `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a dataframe from a function definition, but use 'append' instead. Append works for dictionaries and dataframes. An example for a dictionary based append:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']) #  create empty df with column names. 
append_dict = {'Col1':value_1, 'Col2':value_2, 'Col3':value_3,'Col4':value_4}
df = df.append(append_dict,ignore_index=True).
```

The values can be changed in a loop, so it does something with respect to the previous values. For dataframe append, you can check the pandas documentation (just replace the append_dict argument with the dataframe that you like to append)

Is this what you want?